# kendo values moving beyond dropdown list with optionLabel

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I got dropdown in Kendo. I use OptionLabel, but after using this my values are moving beyond the dropdown:

DropDown code:

[image]

Now how my values are moving beyond the dropdown

[image]

It's better look when I mouseover this value:

[image]

Anyway it's really looking bad. After remove OptionLabel everything is fine:

[image]

Is here any possibility to remove this issue with optionLabel? I need it, because null is also correct value to choose

Comment: Check out for conflicting styles

Answer (score 1):

Give height to your dropdown that can help you to make it more beautiful look
Refer below code for giving height to kendo dropdown

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
   .Height(500)
)
```